# detect system date change, visual basics

Tags: vb.net

I am writing an application on Windows-7 using Visual Basics 2010. I am accessing System Date with

```
Dim today As Integer
today = Format(Now, "dd")
```

Well, that works fine. But I  need some indication/notification when system date changes, so that I can retrieve the new date. Is there any function/way to achieve that ?
Thanks

Comment: Minor point but Visual Basic 2010 is VB.Net, not VB6. Your code isn't obviously any particular variant so I've left the tag.

Answer (score 4):

The system date may change for two reasons:

1. The user manually changed the system date/time.  This can be detected using the method described here:  http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/subclass/datetime.htm
2. Time passes, the clock goes from 23:59:59 to 00:00:00.  I'm don't know of any system event that will tell you when this happens, but you can detect it easily by using a Timer in VB6.  By using a Timer you will get an event at a predefined interval.  You might then check, say everey minute, if the date has changed.
   To use the standard VB6 Timer control, you need a Form on which you put your Timer, but there are other alternatives, like this one:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/TimerLib.aspx

My code example uses the standard VB6 Timer on a Form to watch for "change in minute".  My Timer control has the original name of Timer1

```
Dim iMinute As Integer  'The "current" minute

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Initialize
    iMinute = Format(Now, "n") 'Get the current time as minute
    Timer1.Interval = 1000 'Set interval = 1000 milliseconds
    Timer1.Enabled = True 'Start Timer1 (my Timer)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    'This happens when the given Interval has passed (in this case, every second)
    Dim iMinuteNow As Integer

    iMinuteNow = Format(Now, "n") 
    If iMinuteNow <> iMinute Then  
        MsgBox "You are now in a new minute"
        iMinute = iMinuteNow
    End If
End Sub
```